# Collecting 2d Arrays and Save to File

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

In my c# program i create 2d double arrays continuesly. My question is i want to create another list or array (3d?) and in the end i want to save all 2d arrays to a file. Bellow code append one 2d array to a file how can i save all 2d arrays and save them sameway.
Thanks.

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{ var array = new string[4, 3]; 
  array[0, 0] = "A"; 
  array[0, 1] = "B"; 
  array[0, 2] = "C"; 
  array[1, 0] = "D"; 
  array[1, 1] = "E"; 
  array[1, 2] = "F"; 
  array[2, 0] = "G"; 
  array[2, 1] = "H"; 
  array[2, 2] = "I"; 
  array[3, 0] = "J"; 
  array[3, 1] = "K"; 
  array[3, 2] = "L"; 
  using (var sw = new StreamWriter("outputText.txt")) 
  { 
     for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
     { 
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) 
        { 
           sw.Write(array[i,j] + " "); 
        } 
        sw.Write("\n"); 
     } 
     sw.Flush(); 
     sw.Close(); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: When you say all 2D arrays you only have one... Do you want extra linees breaks between each? One per file?

Comment: In this example yes but in my case there will be around more than 100 2d arrays first i need to save them when as created and in the end with a button i want to save all data to file 2d1 # 2d2# ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're saving them to the same file, decide upon some break character and print it after every array, e.g.

```
1 2 4
5 6 7
#
0 0
3 4
#
9 9
#
```

Represents 3 different 2d arrays. Then, when you're reading the data again, read lines until you hit a `#` character and end the current 2d array / start a new one there. Another thing you might want to do is precede every array with its x/y dimensions, e.g.

```
2 3
0 0
0 0
0 0
#
```

The `2 3` tells us to expect a 2x3 array.

To write, something like this:

```
public void Write(List<string[,]> arrays, string filepath)
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filepath))
    {
        foreach(string[,] array in arrays)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(array.GetLength(0) + " " + array.GetLength(1)); // write dimensions
            int i = 0;
            while(i < array.GetLength(0))
            {
                string line = "";
                int o = 0;
                while(o < array.GetLength(1))
                {
                    line = line + array[i, o];
                    if(o+1 < array.GetLength(1))
                    {
                        line = line + " ";
                    }
                    o++;
                }
                sw.WriteLine(line);
                i++;
            }
            sw.WriteLine("#");
        }
    }
}
```

To read, something like this will get you the whole list of arrays,

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filepath))
{
    bool inarray = false;
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        string s = sr.ReadLine();
        List<string> words = s.Split(' ').ToList();
        string[,] currentArray = null;
        int rowcount = 0;
        List<string[,]> arrays = new List<string[,]>();
        if (!inarray)
        {
            // not in an array, check for dimension numbers
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;
            try
            {
                x = int.Parse(words[0]);
                y = int.Parse(words[1]);
            }
            catch
            {
                continue; // couldn't parse it, try the next line
            }
            inarray = true;
            currentArray = new string[x, y];
            arrays.Add(currentArray);
            rowcount = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            // we're in an array
            // first check if we've hit the # stop character
            if (words[0].Equals("#"))
            {
                inarray = false;
                continue;
            }

            // otherwise, add this row to the array
            int i = 0;
            while(i< words.Count)
            {
                currentArray[i, rowcount] = words[i];
                i++;
            }
            rowcount++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mr. Dechiara thanks. Firstly pls show how to save 2d arrays and then save all to a file ( first method is ok).

Comment: See edit w/ example of how to write arrays to a document in this style.